# Android LocationListener position look like "50.********, 9.********"

Tags: android, location, locationlistener

I'm using a "LocationListener".

And when my app get a result from function "onLocationChanged"
then my data look like

`Location[netowrk 50*****, 19******** ac=12312ms alt=3019]`

somebody know why?
And how to fix ?

Comment: Without any code nobody will know why

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the code. That's what you get when you log the location object.

Comment: I know that... maybe is something with permission?

Comment: try to log location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()

Comment: Then i got in result " 19*********** "

Answer (score 0):

Manifest

```
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />   
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />



  private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener{
    Location mLastLocation;
    public LocationListener(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
        mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {

        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
        mLastLocation.set(location);

        String location_end = ""+location;
        saveToFile("/data/data/com.strziga.spolem/gps.txt", location_end);


    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
    }
}
LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
};
```